# Linking Action to Url

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0

OK, I am retarded so I need explicit instructions how to link the NSURL code section at the bottom to a label click to make a call:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
lblText.text = agencyName;
lblPhone.text = phone;
lblEmail.text = email;
lblAddress.text = agcaddress;



//Set the title of the navigation bar
self.navigationItem.title = @"Agency Info"; 
mapView=[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];



}


- (IBAction)callPlaceNumber:(id)sender {
    NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", phone];
    number = [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                                 withString:@""];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:number]];
}
```

I tried messing with IBActions and Outlets to no avail. Do I need to put an IBAction in my header file and somehow link it to the label? 3rd day coding objective c and I-OS so go easy on me.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question? What exactly you want to do? Open URL onViewLoad or opening URL by clicking on Label?

Comment: Or you want to make a phone call by clicking a button?

Comment: Yeah, open url on by clicking on label. sorry.

Comment: Making the label a link would be ideal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve making a call by clicking on `UILabel` but not recommendable :), The way to do is catch touchEvents and check if the touch event is from the call label than make a call...Something like this,

**Not Recommendable**

Where `calLabel` is an IBOutlet in your header file...

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == callLabel)
    {
        //Your code here which makes a call...
    }
}//In began
```

Or when touch is ending,

```
-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    if ([touch view] == callLabel)
    {
        //Your code here which makes a call...
    }
}//At the end
```

**Recommendable is...**

Create a UIButton make IBAction and write your call logic inside it...Something like this,

```
- (IBAction)callPlaceNumber:(id)sender {
    NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://%@", phoneNumber];
    number = [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                         withString:@""];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:number]];
}
```

Hope this will help!

**EDIT**

```
- (IBAction)callPlaceNumber:(id)sender {
    NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel://12345678"];
    number = [number stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "
                                         withString:@""];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:number]];
}
```

Comment: OK, I changed the code to the above... I added the IBAction to my header file, added a button next to my number that says "call", then then pointed the IBAction to the button. When I run it and click on the button nothing occurs. No errors.

Comment: Put a NSLog in IBAction and check whether it is being called...If yes than NSLog'number' variable before you pass to openURL and check whats getting printed out...try using random number by hardcoding as I given in my EDIT section.

Comment: Yeah, when I did NSLog(number); and every time I click it the number shows in the console. Just doesnt do anything.

Comment: Are you try on simulator? Because on simulator it won't work... :) as there is no Phone on it...You gotta test it on real device

Comment: setting a breakpoint at [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:number]]; it hits and shows the link tel://1111111 still no action though. Wierd

Comment: For android it does, as they use emulator but not in iOS development :)

Comment: Yeah dude I enjoy Android development, this is hell... especially on a hackintosh